# How do I create a follow - follow system in my django project?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm trying to create a follow - following system like instagram / twitter but i'm struggling to get the POST action to work and change the follows field.

I've created the models.py, the url.py and a button form on the profile.html template, but cannot get the views.py to work with my class based detail profile view.

If I update the follows in the admin panel, the button shows the right info, e.g if logged in user is following the viewed user profile it shows 'unfollow', and if they're not followed, it shows 'follow'

**updated** when you now click the follow / unfollow button it directs to whatever the action value is, eg. follow-test-action, without changing the state of the button.

```
class NewUser(AbstractUser):
    user = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="profile", symmetrical=False, blank=True)
    slug =  AutoSlugField(populate_from='first_name', unique_with='last_name')
    follows = models.ManyToManyField("self", related_name="followed_by", symmetrical=False, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Views.py of profile detail view:

```
class FollowView(View):
    model = NewUser
    def get_context_data(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        profile = get_object_or_404(NewUser, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        if request.method == "POST":
            action = request.POST['follow']
            if action == "unfollow":
                profile.follows.remove(request.profile)
            elif action == "follow":
                profile.follows.add(request.user)
            profile.follows.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('follow', args=[str(pk)]))
```

urls.py

```
path('user/<slug>', FollowView.as_view, name='follow'),
```

now the button directs to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/follow-test-action"

```
# form
<form method=POST action="follow-test-action">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% if newuser in user.follows.all %}
        <button class = "btn btn-sm btn-light rounded-3" name="follow" value="unfollow" type="submit">unfollow</button>
    {% else %}
        <button class = "btn btn-sm  btn-outline-success rounded-3" name="follow" value="follow" type="submit">Follow</button>
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

Is there another solution, i'm clutching at straws here being new

Answer (score 0):

As you're using Class Based Views, it's best to use them for following too.

It seems that now your Follow form doesn't know where to go, to which url. For that, you need attribute "action" in your form. Something like this: `<form method=POST action="form_url">`

That url needs to be associated with a view, that is dedicated for handling follows.

As you're using class based views, it's best to use them here too.

You would need a new View class, for example `FollowView`

on that class you would need a `post` method which would handle your follows (similar to what is in your `profile` view).

Then the url on your form (attribute action) should be the url that you attach to this view.

By the way, I see you're handling authentication yourself. Django has `login_required` decorator and mixin (decorator for function based views, mixin - for class based views) that handles this for you.

Comment: Updated to reflect your input with class based views, now buttons direct to the value from the form action, not applying the form action that's defined in the view. Any ideas of a better method?

Comment: Maybe I didn't write the answer clearly enough. 

`action` needs to hold a url. Google "html forms action". This url needs to lead to a view which handles form data. Let's call that view `FollowView`. That view needs to have a `post` method. In this `post` method you need to do the logic for follow. 

Also, your form is lacking the data of user you want to follow. You need to send that too, not only "follow" or "unfollow" options. You can do it with a hidden field.